# Should the " Constantipolitan" hat be named " Constantinopolitan"?

Tags: support, status-completed, winter-bash-2012

"Constantipolitan," the name of a hat on the Winter Bash page, looks like a typo to me (although I don't blame anybody for mis-typing such a long and rarely used word). Shouldn't it be Constanti**no**politan?

Comment: Istanbul is Constantiple?

Comment: @mmyers No, that would be Istnbul ;-)

Comment: http://vimeo.com/6746927 :)

Comment: No, you can't go back to Constantinopolitan

Comment: Googling `Constantipolitan` now returns Meta.SO results :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's supposed to be a portmanteau of *Constantinople* and *cosmopolitan* — because Fez hats were worn by Turkish people, and because fezzes are cool. Also, I didn't know it was a *real* word.

Technically, yes, it should probably be *Constantinopolitan*. But in my opinion, *Constantipolitan* is easier to say and kind of rhymes with itself. :)

We'll "fix" the spelling — no one knew it was a real word! Thanks for pointing that out everyone.

Comment: The "cosmopolitan" part is rather hard to guess because of "aliasing" issues with the ending of "constantinopolitan". I think that "Cosmontinopolian" would have been easier to "parse" :)

Comment: What's wrong with `cosmopolitan Constantinopolian`? Or `completely cosmopolitan Constantinopolian`

Comment: @Pekka lines can only have so many characters.

Comment: Constanti-mopolitan?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Fun fact: parsing applies to natural languages too, no need for the quotes ;)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Right... At some point, my programming mentality settled in so deeply that I almost convinced myself that a kilometer is 1024 meters. On the other hand, I'm sure some linguists probably think that a kilobyte is 1000 bytes :)

Answer (score 5):

I agree, for me too, it looks like a typo, and when I tried to search for its meaning, Google suggested me *[Constantinopolitan](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Constantinopolitan)*, but I don't know if there is anything to do to change that now.

Comment: Congratulations, this post has just earned you a "Constantipolitan" hat :)

Comment: I see ... but I would have preferred the Constantinopolitan one ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the correct word should be Constantinopolitan. It comes originally from [Constantine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantine_the_Great) who was a Roman emperor. Before that the city was known under the name of [Byzantium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantium). Subsequently, the city was then renamed Constantinopolis ("Constantine's City" or Constantinople in English). In this case *Constantinopolitan* means, people that who lives in *Constantinople* or *Constantinopolis* in Latin.

If you look at the meaning of [polis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polis), you will see that **Polis** literally means city in Greek.

According to this, when we dig into to recent history, Turkey City Name Changes 28th March 1930, Two of Turkey's largest cities change their names ( Constantinople and Angora ).
The City of Constantinople is changed to [Istanbul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Istanbul)
The City of Angora is changed to Ankara. (If you want to get an idea about the names list of Istanbul, you may check out [Istanbul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_Istanbul))

Fezzes were cool :) I agree with that. It is cool until we approach that as a cultural inheritance :) If we want to get more information about [**Fez**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fez_(hat)), we recognize that not the only Turkish people were into that.  Interestingly enough, the article says that 'The fez is a part of the traditional clothing of [Cyprus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyprus)'.

I strongly believe that, having 'Constantinopolitan' hat is a good thing that if you want to know what it is all about. It's beyond its meaning. It's an ancient word :)

Answer (score 2):

I actually prefer the mis-spelling - it is easier to pronounce (not that its a word I will be using too often verbally)

Comment: That's kind of what I thought! :P

Comment: Maybe just for those who didn't know the real word :)

Comment: That's also true!

Comment: Yeah I find the correct spelling more natural to pronounce only because I've never come across the misspelling :P

Answer (score 1):

Myself, I assumed it was meant to be read as "constant-ipolitan"... implying, perhaps, that on Meta all members are declared constant--read-only, able to look but not change anything.